Crafting Perspex
I'm making fan art, Wheelie Yellow, (kid friendly) for 3D printing, based upon a cheap kid-friendly (scanned 3D) RC car.
To give you an impression of the current phase of the 3D drawing see the left:

I'm thinking though that I want to add perspex glass in it, for the windows.
And while I am handy with 3D printers and drawing.
I'm less familiar with handling Perspex.
I know i can cut a large plate in half.
But how do you work with small pieces? To get round corners etc.?

I’m voting to close this question because does not appear to be about tools and applications of 3D printing, within the scope defined in the help center but may fit better on another site in the Stack Exchange network, i.e. Arts & Crafts.

I think this is very open towards thinker es , this is just another material used in our builds. and a kind of plastic as well, i think helpfull to others as well

I'm not saying that it is not helpful, this is just not the right site for the question. The post is asking about the acrylic itself whereas the mention of 3D printing is describing where the acrylic will be used.

Perspex is very easy to work with, while large cuts, like cutting in half, can be precut with a knife and bend to break at the line. For smaller pieces, a manual jigsaw  works fine.
Perspex is pretty easy to mechanically machine, provided you keep the temperature low. This guide from https://www.theplasticshop.co.uk has some tips on machining Perspex.
Note that Perspex can also be laser cut. In the early printer days, frames of some kits were made from laser cut Perspex/acrylic (usually cheapest acrylic they could source); e.g. the Anet A8/A6.
To get this question on topic and related to 3D Printing, you could add a laser module or something like a Dremel and attach this to the print head or replace the print head, you could CNC the part you require.
